# Sum of odd numbers from 101 to 201

Tags: c

I want to write a program in C which will print the sum of all odd numbers from 101 to 201. Please help.

```
int i,t,s;
i=101;
s=0; 
while(i<=201)
{
  t=i+2;
  s=s+t;
  i+=2;
}
printf("sum is %d",s);
```

Comment: First figure out how to format the code on this site, then tell us what exactly you are struggling with.

Comment: If you know how to use a for/while loop and the modulus operator, this should be easy. Here is more info about the Modulus operator in C https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html

Comment: You don't need so many variables. It helps if you give them meaningful names, too. I'd start out by setting your total equal to 101, and then add all the _other_ numbers

Comment: How about using a simple arithmetic series sum formula?

Comment: solve simpler problems first. write code to add the numbers from 1 to 10. then 50 to 100. work up to your goal.

Comment: Wha's the point of `t`?  Just use `i`.  In fact `t` has the wrong value when you use it, it's 2 too high.

Comment: @EugeneSh. you are right, there is a formula, I put in my answer how to find one and implemented it

Comment: Hitanshu Gedam I explained why you computed wrong and given a solution with a loop and an other without a loop, see my answer

Answer (score 3):

doing

> ```
> int i,t,s;
> i=101;
> s=0; 
> while(i<=201)
> {
>   t=i+2;
>   s=s+t;
>   i+=2;
> }
> printf("sum is %d",s);
> ```

the first value you sum is `i+2` being `101+2` being 103, so you miss to add 101

Of course a way to correct it to initialize *s* with 101 rather than 0, but it is possible to simplify your code and to make it more readable, for instance :

```
int s = 0;

for (int i = 101; i <= 201; i += 2)
  s += i;
```

---

But a serial like that can have a formula

We want `101+103+105+...+201` this is `(1+3+5+...+201)` - `(1+3+5+...+99)` so if we know how to compute `1+3+5+...+(2*n+1)` without a loop we can compute the expected value without a loop too.

- we know all that `1+2+3+...+n` is `n*(n+1)/2`
- and we want in fact `1+2+3+4+...+(2*m+1) - (2+4+6+8+...+(2*m))`
- having `2+4+6+8+...+(2*m)` is `2*(1+2+3+...+m)`
- finaly `1+3+5+...+(2*m+1)` is `(2*m+1)*(2*m+2)/2 - 2*m*(m+1)/2`

So, to compute the value between 2 odd values (here 101 and 201) the program can be :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sumOdd(int m)
{
   m /= 2; /* m in my formula */
   return (2*m+1)*(2*m+2)/2 - 2*m*(m+1)/2;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
   int n1, n2;

   if (argc != 3)
     printf("Usage: %s <odd1> <odd2>", *argv);
   else if ((sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &n1) != 1) ||
            (sscanf(argv[2], "%d", &n2) != 1) ||
            (n1 < 1) ||
            ((n2 - n1) < 2) ||
            ((n1 & n2 & 1) != 1))
     fprintf(stderr, "wrong values %d %d\n", n1, n2);
   else
     printf("%d\n", sumOdd(n2) - sumOdd(n1 - 2));

   /* use the loop to check the formula result */
   int s = 0;

   for (int i = n1; i <= n2; i += 2)
     s += i;
   printf("%d\n", s);
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -g -pedantic -Wall -Wextra s.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 101 201
7701
7701
```

Works !

Comment: It was a very long time since I had not done math like this ^^

Comment: Instead of forcing the user to enter odd numbers, you can round your start up to an odd number with `n1 |= 1`.  That lets you count odd numbers in any integer range, even if the start point isn't odd.  (The end point still Just Works if even for the naive loop.  For the closed-form formula, I guess you'd want to round it down to an even number with `n2 &= ~1U;` to clear the low bit)

Answer (score 1):

The variable `t`isn't needed - just add `i` to `s`. Like

```
int i,s;
i=101;
s=0; 
while(i<=201)
{
  s=s+i;
  i+=2;
}
printf("sum is %d",s);
```

Comment: There is also a formula to remove the loop ;-)